# GET vs POST where to use which method

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm having a little confusion regarding what should be the ideal case for using `GET` and `POST` for a Ajax call. Previously when we were using `ASP.NET MVC` with `KnockoutJS`, we used to call a custom `$.postJson(url,data,callback)` from `jQuery` to our `MvcController`(even for a `GET` operation). Recently we are using `ASP.NET Web API` with `AngularJS` and using `$http(url,method)` with `GET` and passing the search parameters in our url attribute and catching them in `ApiController` using `FromUri` attribute.

Now my question is, what should be the ideal scenarios and best practice for using `GET` & `POST` (P.S. Do not answer from `CRUD` operations perspective).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a formal definition of what the methods should be doing on the server side: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Because of that formal definition, any *ideal* answer inevitably ends up sounding like a CRUD answer. GET should never modify data, it should only retrieve data. POST is intended to change data on the server.

In *practice*, we often find ourselves using POST as a work around for the fact that GET is effectively limited from having a content body in the request. Many data retrieval scenarios may need to send a content body to the server. You may also run into URL length issues in some GET scenarios that may cause you to send data in POST. So, if you're trying to retrieve data, prefer GET and use POST where you need to.

While I may use POST to work around limitations of GET for data retrieval, I would *never* use GET to modify data.

Comment: Thumbs up! pretty much sums up everything. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

Use POST if you are going to add & update.
Use GET if you are going to fetch.

For Best Practice:
for log-in, use POST for submitting credentials which hides the username/password from being sniffed.

Comment: POST does not protect username and password from being 'sniffed' It might hide it on the querystring, but it is still accessible. PUT is also used for updating, POST for inserting (if looking at best practices)

Comment: To be honest I really don't know why they were only using $.postJson previously(even for a search operation). I tried to confront but it seemed everyone was using it without thinking too much.